# Using NVM to start Node in an Upstart Job

Tags: node.js, upstart, nvm

I am trying to start my Node server inside an ubuntu upstart process. I really want to use my NVM environment. But I just can't seem to get it going.

Does anyone have a code snippet of an upstart job that launches their node application within a node virtual environment.

Comment: I have a snippet code of using upstart to launch a node application. but I don't understand what do u mean by within a node virtual environment. hmmmm

Comment: @murvinlai I mean NVM (Node version manager) - sorry, I got confused.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script command to `exec bash -c 'source /home/dev/nvm/nvm.sh && exec node app'` where /home/dev/nvm/nvm.sh is the filepath of your nvm.sh file see also http://doctrina.org/NodeJS-Under-NVM-With-Upstart.html